# express post 500 error without router/subsite

Tags: node.js, express, angular

My setup is as follows:

posting to `/register` will take the arguments and register a user via passport and mongoose. If this returns an `UserExistsError` the server sends this info to the client (via http error handling).

However the server also displays a 500 server error which should not occur.

This is because of the `next()` which as far as I understand routes the client to `/register`. `/register` itself does not exists as a page (only as the postadress as stated in the code)

So my question is: How to handle the response to not be an error or supress it? Can I use something else instead of next() to stop the redirect to `/register`? I just want the server to stop doing anything/going out of that function at that point.

Code:

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('server registering user');
  User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(err) {
    let tempstring = ""+err;
    if(tempstring.indexOf("UserExistsError") !== -1){
      return next(err); //get out of the function and into normal operation under '/'
    }
  });
});
```

This topic is bugging me and I might just missunderstand something trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `/register` is a post only route you still need to send a response. If you don't send a response of some kind, the request will hang and eventually timeout in the browser. I would suggest sending a json response like so.

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('server registering user');
  User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(err) {
    let tempstring = ""+err;
    if(tempstring.indexOf("UserExistsError") !== -1){
      return next(err); //get out of the function and into normal operation under '/'
    }
    res.json({message: 'message here'});
  });
});
```

This will send a 200 OK reponse with some json in the body.

If you just want to pass the request down the line you need to call next without an err object like so.

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('server registering user');
  User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(err) {
    let tempstring = ""+err;
    if(tempstring.indexOf("UserExistsError") !== -1){
      return next(err); //get out of the function and into normal operation under '/'
    }
    //call next without an error
    next();
  });
});
```

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve, but if there is no route that matches it will just go to an error 500.

Comment: Your second suggestion moved the error from 500 to 404 because the client cannot find the /register. So I cannot post under a virtual link/subsite? It is a one-page application, so I wanted to avoid creating extra pages.

Comment: That is what I expected to happen as there is no other route that it will match. In my first example you are sending a json response which is pretty standard with single page applications. With a request whether it is a post or a get you need a response. It is not creating a "page" it is just an api call really

Comment: Using the res.json before the return helped avoiding any error (my fault). Now I need to fiddle with the json response a bit. For now it seems the problem itself is fixed (will mark if nothing connecting comes up). I am using angular2's http module to post and then use map and subscribe on that relating data to a handlingDataFunc and err to an errorHandlerFunc